# Is it a good practice to always join SQL tables?

Tags: sql, mongodb, postgresql, join

I am writing a web app using `sequelize` as my ORM for SQL database (`PostgreSQL`).
I have more experience in `MongoDB` instead of SQL databases, and I keep on looking for a way to query the full model in one request.

Let's say I have a `User` and `Comment` models, and `User` may have many `Comment`s.
I keep the `Comment` and `User` in different tables (and they also are split into separate tables).
When I want to query the `User`, should I create the query using `join` to get the comments as well?
Is it a good or bad practice to execute full joins between all the models relations on every query?

Comment: It's perfectly normal to do joins between tables; this is what relational database were created for.  You can add indices on the join columns for better performance.

Comment: If you're using an ORM, do you think you should be querying the database directly?  Let the ORM handle querying of the data layer - leverage the ORM and let it do its job.

Comment: Yes of course I will leverage the orm and won't write it myself, but I still need to tell the orm to execute the join.

Answer (score 2):

Using JOINS, you can fetch exactly the data you want from any number of tables with just one query, using any search parameter you chose to filter the results. MySQL can also utilize things such as Indexes to maximize performance, which your API code can not.

Generally speaking, executing multiple queries and using some sort of API, such as PHP, to filter the results creates a lot more overhead for the servers. A lot more data has to be sent back and forth between MySQL and the API, not to mention that MySQL is built for optimal performance, which is in no way guaranteed when dealing with per-developer API code.

So in your case, go with a join on user, Comment.